# Any tips on why tikzpicture is failing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, groupplots

I'm running the following, and it doesn't seem to work. Any tips on what is going wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1},height=6cm,width=6cm,xmin=0.5,ymin=0.4999,ymax=1.0001,xmax=1,samples=500,ytick={0.5,1},xtick={0.5,1}, xlabel={$v_1$},
    axis lines=left]
        \nextgroupplot[title={}, ylabel={$x_1$}]
              \addplot[blue,]{min(1,(\x/(2*(1-min(1,\x)))))};\label{plots:plot1};   

              \addplot[black] {max(0,min((3*\x-1)/(2*\x),1))};\label{plots:plot2};
                \addplot[black, dashed] {(\x)};\label{plots:plot3};
         \nextgroupplot[title={}, ylabel={}]
              \addplot[blue]{max(min((2-3*\x)/(2-2*\x),1),0)};\label{plots:plot4};  

              \addplot[black] {};\label{plots:plot5};
                \addplot[black, dashed] {1-\x};\label{plots:plot6};
                \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
                \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- 
          node[anchor=south,rotate=90] { } 
          (bot-|current bounding box.west); % legend \path (top|-current bounding box.south)--
      coordinate(legendpos) 
      (bot|-current bounding box.south); \matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw   ]at([yshift=-1ex, xshift=-17ex]legendpos)   {
    \ref{plots:plot1}& player 1 moves first&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot2}& player 2 moves first&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot3}& players move simultaneously& \\}; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. you should use `x`, not `\x`, in `pgfplots` functions;
2. what throws the error — you can find it by commenting out everything and then uncommenting one `\addplot` alone — is

   ```
   \addplot[black] {};\label{plots:plot5};
   ```

which is illegal; I do not know what do you want to plot here...

(PS: look at the warnings and add a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` or whatever to use the newest features of the package).